# DRF serializing response fails with ValueError: Circular reference detected when variable is included

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my DRF app I have a view to generate reports. The report generation takes some time, but I want to give back data about the reports that will be generated. For now list of filenames of the report and a simple message that reports will be generated.

For some reason it does not like to include the list "filenames" in the response. I always get error with "circular reference".

This is my ViewSet:

```
class RequestReportGeneration(viewsets.ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (
        TokenAuthentication,
        SessionAuthentication,
        BasicAuthentication,
    )
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = serializers.RequestReportSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = serializers.RequestReportSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        report_type = serializer.validated_data.get("report_type")
        ids = serializer.validated_data.get("ids")
        options = serializer.validated_data.get("options")
        match report_type:
            case "1":
                acls = ACL.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
                if len(acls)>0:
                    filenames = []
                    timestamp = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
                    for acl in acls:
                        # create filename
                        device_name = acl.device.name
                        acl_name = acl.name
                        filename = f"Matrix_Report_{device_name}_{acl_name}_{timestamp}"
                        # create job for report generation
                        generate_matrix_report.delay(acl, filename)
                        filenames.append(filenames)
                        data = {"message": "Reports generation requested successfully", "reports": filenames}
                    response_serializer = serializers.RequestReportResponseSerializer(data=data)
                    response_serializer.is_valid()
                    return Response(data=response_serializer.data)
                    
                else:
                    raise ValidationError("No valid Rulebase IDs")
            case _:
                raise ValidationError("Not a valid Report Type")
```

This is my serializer for the response:

```
class RequestReportResponseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    message = serializers.CharField()
    reports = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
```

I have also tried to give back a dictionary without serialzier, but get the same error with "circular reference".

```
return Response({"message": "Reports generation requested successfully", "reports": filenames})
```

Comment: if serializer contain fileName field then it will show filename if not then it will not show

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The problem is that I get an error with "circular reference".